# relative position inheritance when not set

Tags: html, css, position

Trying to build a 3d cube effect around a content area. Cube effect is working properly with `::before`,`::after` and `-webkit-transform:skew`, however I cannot get the right side to inherit the height of its parent forcing me to use a static height, which I do not want to do. Is there any better way to carry this out, due to a default height not being set as content will continually be more/less and effect size?

JS Fiddle below, HTML formatted a little to simplify.

http://jsfiddle.net/pm9h5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absolutely position the `:after` pseudo element relative to the parent `.cube` and use a height of `100%` to take the height of the parent.

Using this method, the 3D shadow effect should work for dynamic content of varying dimensions.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LY6s7/)

Add `position:relative` to the parent:

```
.cube {
    content:'';
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Add `position:absolute` and `height:100%` to `:before`:

```
.cube::before {
    content:'';
    width: 35px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -35px;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```